# Слово "высокодивидендный"

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Здравствуйте. Возникла сложность с написанием слова "высокодивидендный". Это что-то (акция, ценная бумага), приносящее высокий дивиденд. В словарях такого слова нет, чисто интуитивно хочется написать слитно, но практика склоняется к раздельному написанию. Помогите, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Слово, действительно, пишется слитно, так как используется в качестве термина - устойчивого словосочетания, применяемого в различных областях человеческой деятельности.

Термины образуются из словосочетания наречия и прилагательного или причастия ПУТЁМ СРАЩЕНИЯ: дикорастущий, вечнозеленый, дорогостоящий, высококачественный, легкораненый, узкоспециальный, малоизвестный,  многообещающий.

Существование конкретного термина следует уточнять по словарю, однако это слово относится к новой лексике и может отсутствовать в словарях.